# How to filter and execute with array of multiple types?

Tags: typescript

I have an array which may have two types `A` and `B`. I would like to perform actions over items of one type.

```
type A = {
  propA: number
}
type B = {
  propB: string
}
type MyArray = Array<A|B>
const anArrayOfBothAAndB: MyArray = [{ propA: 1 }, { propB: '2' }]

anArrayOfBothAAndB.filter((item) => {
  return (item as A).propA
})
.forEach((item: A) => { // reports error here
  console.log(item.propA)
})
```

I can add code like `const itemA: A = item as any` to make `console.log(itemA.propA)` work, but it looks not elegant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that TypeScript isn't smart enough to detect that all elements of the array should be of type `A` after the filtration. You need to declare the return type of the filter function as `item is A`. See the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates).

Fixed version:

```
type A = {
  propA: number
}
type B = {
  propB: string
}
type MyArray = Array<A|B>
const anArrayOfBothAAndB: MyArray = [{ propA: 1 }, { propB: '2' }]

anArrayOfBothAAndB.filter((item): item is A => {
  return (item as A).propA !== undefined
})
.forEach((item) => { // no more error, don't even have to specify type
  console.log(item.propA)
})
```

Comment: this is a very neat solution. Did not know this was possible

Answer (score 0):

Well, since 2020, some things have changed in the TypeScript world. The `filter` method may be used with a generic parameter. [Here's](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) the perfect example, also with the `filter` method ;)

Given the code snippet you've pasted here.

```js
type A = {
  propA: number
}
type B = {
  propB: string
}
type MyArray = Array<A|B>
const anArrayOfBothAAndB: MyArray = [{ propA: 1 }, { propB: '2' }]

anArrayOfBothAAndB.filter((item) => {
  return (item as A).propA
})
.forEach((item: A) => { // reports error here
  console.log(item.propA)
})
```

There should be a difference in the first `filter()` call, so it should be like this:

```js
anArrayOfBothAAndB.filter<A>((item): item is A => {
    return 'propA' in item;
}).forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item.propA)
})
```

The difference is that you pass a `predicate function` (also called `type guard`) as the `filter` callback. So you give to the `filter` this *guard* which assures the new array that it's the type you predicate.